# FileReader memory leak in Chrome

Tags: javascript, memory, file-upload, memory-leaks, filereader

I have a webpage with file upload functionality. The upload is performed in 5MB chunks. I want to calculate hash for each chunk before sending it to the server. The chunks are represented by [Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Blob) objects. In order to calculate the hash I am reading such blob into an [ArrayBuffer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ArrayBuffer) using a native [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/FileReader). Here is the code:

```
var reader = new FileReader();

var getHash = function (blob, callback) {
    reader.onloadend = function (e) {
        var hash = util.hash(e.target.result);
        callback(hash);
    };
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);
}

var processChunk = function (chunk) {
    if (chunk) {
        getHash(chunk, function (hash) {
            util.sendToServer(chunk, hash, function() {
                // this callback is called when chunk upload is finished
                processChunk(chunks.shift());
            });
        });
    }
}

var chunks = file.splitIntoChunks(); // gets an array of blobs
processChunk(chunks.shift());
```

The problem: using the `FileReader.readAsArrayBuffer` seems to eat up a lot of memory which is not released. So far I tested with a 5GB file on following browsers:

- Chrome 55.0.2883.87 m (64-bit): the memory goes up to 1-2GB quickly and oscillates around that. Sometimes it goes all the way up and browser tab crashes. It can use more memory than the size of read chunks. E.g. after reading 500MB of chunks the process already uses 700MB of memory.
- Firefox 50.1.0: memory usage oscillates around 300-600MB

Code adjustments I have tried - all to no avail:

- re-using the same `FileReader` instance for all chunks (as suggested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32102361/filereader-memory-leak))
- creating new `FileReader` for each chunk
- adding timeout before starting new chunk
- setting the `FileReader` and the `ArrayBuffer` to null after each read

The question: is there a way to fix the problem? Is this a bug in the FileReader implementations or am I doing something wrong?

**EDIT**: Here is a JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/andy250/pjt9udeu/

Comment: I tried with Chrome 55.0.2883.87 m (64-bit) as well - getting about the same consumption of memory when running your JsFiddle. See video clip: http://screencast.com/t/e7eQkVMWI68a.

Also tested Internet Explorer 11 - it only uses about 130 MB RAM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug in Chrome on Windows. It is reported here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=674903

Comment: Is there any solution 3 years after the original post?