# How to release Array Buffer memory when using File Reader readAsArrayBuffer?

Tags: javascript, filereader

I'm having problems to use FileReader readAsArrayBuffer

Using Chrome I ran [this](http://jsfiddle.net/avnerm/ctkga25w/30/) jsfiddle example

1. step1. I select to open a big file (~1.5 GB)
      The file is read ok:

   - the Html text changes from *Before readAsArrayBuffer* to *After readAsArrayBuffer*
   - the print to the console shows an array buffer of size ~1.5 GB (ArrayBuffer(1482268150))
2. step2. I select another file (~300 MB) and the file is read ok:

   - the Html text changes from *Before readAsArrayBuffer* to *After readAsArrayBuffer*
   - the print to the console shows an array buffer of size ~300 MB (ArrayBuffer(1482268150))

As I repeat steps 1 and 2, the Memory footprint increases on every call in Chrome's "Task Manager" 
Eventually, I see an OUT_OF_MEMORY error message, the displayed HTML text stops changing, and no more print-outs to the console (see attached table)

According to [here](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/memory-problems/)

> The Memory column represents native memory. DOM nodes are stored in
>   native memory. If this value is increasing, DOM nodes are getting
>   created.

In my case, I don't add any DOM elements, so I don't understand this definition of *Memory*.

I looked for ways to free the memory, but everywhere I read that the browser takes care of this via Garbage Collection.
Since the read happens inside a local function, and the array buffer is assigned to a local variable, I expect GC to kick in and free memory, but this does not happen.

**[![How should I release the memory after FileReader readAsArrayBuffer?]**

Thanks

---

p.s. I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41181923/filereader-memory-leak-in-chrome?rq=1) link. In my case it happens on Ubuntu 18.04 on Chrome 79

[image: observations from the example]
jsfiddle code

```
<form>
<input id="input" type="file"></input>
</form>
<pre id="output"></pre>

var input = $('#input');
var output = $('#output');

function readFile(f) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsText(f);
    reader.onload = function() {
        var text = reader.result;
        output.html("");
        output.html(text);
    };
    reader.onerror = function(e) {
        console.log("Error:", e);
    };
}

function readFile2(f) {
    let reader = new FileReader();
      output.html("Before readAsArrayBuffer");
    try{
        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(f);
        reader.onload = function(fileLoadedEvent) {
            let arrayBuffer = fileLoadedEvent.target.result;
            console.log('arrayBuffer: ', arrayBuffer);

            // output.html("");
            output.html("After readAsArrayBuffer");
        };
    }
    catch(e)
    {
        output.html("Error reading");
    }
}


input.bind("change", function(e) {
    var file = e.currentTarget.files[0];
    readFile2(file);
});


pre {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: wrap;
}
```

Comment: Since the console is live, it will prevent your logged objects from being collected by the GarbageCollector. That's not an issue you should face in production.

Comment: Thanks @Kaiido I verified that console.clear() or printing the arrayBuffer.byteLength prevents accumulation in memory.